# Python lazy iterator

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to understand how and when iterator expressions get evaluated. The following seems to be a lazy expression:

```
g = (i for i in range(1000) if i % 3 == i % 2)
```

This one, however fails on construction:

```
g = (line.strip() for line in open('xxx', 'r') if len(line) > 10)
```

I do not have the file named 'xxx'. However, since this thing is lazy, why is it failing so soon?

Thanks.

EDI: Wow, I made a lazy one!

```
g = (line.strip() for i in range(3) for line in open(str(i), 'r'))
```

Comment: for i in range(1) is three times as lazy as for i in range(3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html):

> Variables used in the generator
>   expression are evaluated lazily in a
>   separate scope when the `next()`
>   method is called for the generator
>   object (in the same fashion as for
>   normal generators). However, the `in`
>   expression of the leftmost `for`
>   clause is immediately evaluated in the
>   current scope so that an error
>   produced by it can be seen before any
>   other possible error in the code that
>   handles the generator expression.

Answer (score 6):

The iteration over the file returned by the call to `open()` is lazy. The call to `open()` is not.