# Do lazy imperative programming languages exist? If not, why not?

Tags: lazy-evaluation, imperative-languages

If I'm not mistaken, the concept of a "lazy imperative programming language" makes perfect sense.

For example, I envision that the following code should cause the program to print "7"

```
a <- 1
b <- a+5
a <- 2
print([b])
```

while the following code should cause the program to print "6"

```
a <- 1
b <- [a+5]
a <- 2
print(b)
```

and the following code should cause the program to print the string "a+5"

```
a <- 1
b <- a+5
a <- 2
print(b)
```

The idea is that `[..]` flattens an expression by performing an evaluation, using the current values of each variable.

> **Question.** Do lazy imperative programming languages exist, and if not, why not? Is there any particular reason why they cannot *ever* exist?

Comment: In some ways Python 3 is a lazy imperative programming language.

Comment: @JohnColeman, I like that you have a background in universal algebra. Can you elaborate a little regarding the laziness of Python 3?

Comment: It was just an off-hand remark. Python3 is so multi-paradigm that it is difficult to classify, but it is clearly closer to being an imperative language than a functional one (especially if you view object-oriented as a sub-type of imperative). On the other hand, Python makes very heavy use of lazy *iterators*. E.g. `(n**2 for n in range(10))` produces no squares until you try to iterate over it -- or pass it to a function like `sum` which implicitly iterates over it. This was the case even in Python2 but was made more extensive in Python3. The core evaluation strategy is still eager, though.

Comment: Being multi-paradigm is the rule rather than the exception nowadays. I don't see any imperative language following Haskell's footsteps and being lazy by default, but versions of lazy streams/iterators are becoming more common (e.g. Java 8's streams). See this for a bit about laziness in Python: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2249651/4996248

Comment: The criterion for a language to be lazy is that it needs to be referentially transparent. In that case, it does not matter when an expression is evaluated - the program will still yield the same result.

Comment: Any language that supports anonymous functions could operate this way. Take Javascript for example: `var a = 1; var b = () => a + 5; a = 2; console.log(b());` which prints "7" because `b` wraps the expression in a lambda that is defined when `a` is 1 but not executed until `a` is set to 2. The `[]` syntax in your example code could just be interpreted as the syntax to execute a function-wrapped expression, so your second example would instead look like `var a = 1; var b = (() => a + 5)(); a = 2; console.log(b);` which would print "6".